# If the Rref(A) of a 3x3 matrix is I(A), is this a valid eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For the vector A:
EDIT: I had originally multiplied the matrix by -1. Apologies.
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 4 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I got $\lambda I_n - A$ as:

\begin{bmatrix}
(\lambda - 4) & -2 & -2\\
-2 & (\lambda - 4) & -2\\
-2 & -2 & (\lambda - 4)\\
\end{bmatrix}

(Apologies for the bad formatting, it's a 3x3 (diagonal? or orthogonal?) matrix.

With corresponding Eigenvalues of $\lambda = 0, \lambda = 6$

For $\lambda = 0;$

I got an Identity Matrix as follows,

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]$$

where the right hand column of 0's is the 0 vector you want when you multiply the left-hand side by \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\\end{bmatrix}

Is $v_1 = v_2 = v_3 = 0$ a valid Eigenvector/Eigenspace?

**EDIT: I got the eigenvalues as follows:**

Using Sarrus' Rule with the $\lambda I_n - A$ matrix:

$X = (\lambda -4)(\lambda -4)(\lambda -4) + (-2)^3 + (-2)^3$ (along the \ diagonal)

$Y = (-2)(-2)(\lambda -4) + (\lambda -4)(-2)(-2) + (-2)(\lambda -4)(-2)$ (along the / diagonal from the right)

Let $Z = X - Y$, thus giving me the polynomial.

Comment: That's not $\lambda I_n + A,$ what you calculated was $\lambda I + A$. None of the eigenvalues of $A$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: Also, how did you decide what the eigenvalues are?  For instance, $0$ is not an eigenvalue of your matrix.

Comment: @5xum I actually wrote down the wrong matrix! There were no negative numbers in the original, could you take a look at this one please?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I calculated the $det(\lambda I_n - A)$ and using Sarrus' rule got the polynomial $\lambda^3 - 12\lambda^2 + 36\lambda = 0$ and got $\lambda = 6$ or $0$.

Comment: @Gabi Still, the second part of my comment holds: None of the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$. Can you show your calculation of the eigenvalues? Tell us how you got to the polynomial (it is wrong).

Comment: @5xum I showed my calculations in a previous comment.

Comment: @Gabi you miscalculated the determinant; you should end up with $(\lambda-8)(\lambda - 2)^2$.  That is,
$$
\lambda^2 - 12\lambda^2 + 36\lambda - 32
$$
For some reason, you've left out the constant term

Comment: @Gabi How did you get to the polynomial? That's where you made your mistake.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Will I just use the traditional way of getting the determinant instead of using Sarrus' Rule instead? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @5xum I put my calculations into the question.

Comment: @Gabi Sarrus' Rule is fine, but you made a mistake on the sign.  You should have ended up with $-16 - 16 = -32$ as a constant term rather than $-16 + 16 = 0$

Comment: @Gabi The constant term is calculated incorrectly. You have a constant term of $-80$ for $X$ and a constant term of $-48$ for $Y$. That adds up to $-80 - (-48) = -32$ for $X-Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments: you've calculated the determinant incorrectly.  When you fix your mistake, you should end up with the characteristic polynomial
$$
\lambda^3 - 12 \lambda^2 + 36\lambda - 32 = (\lambda - 8)(\lambda - 2)^2
$$